# Regexp - Search for start of words

Tags: mysql, regex, search

Hello im building a website and im searching place names by name. i need a regexp to match in the following situations....

```
Search = Lon

Matches
Londonderry
Greater London

But no match in
Millon
```

I've tried '`^Lon`' but this doesnt show Greater london,

I've tried just '`Lon`' but this matches millon,

I've also messed around with word boundaries but cant get it working correctly.
Im sure this is simple but regexp is classically tricky.

Comment: i had some thoughts about how todo it in regexp but either they are too genral and bring back 'millon' or skip 'Greater London'......

Comment: (^SEARCH|\bSEARCH) - doesnt work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In MySQL you can mark word boundaries in Regexp by using `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`.

So this should work in your WHERE clause:

```
regexp '[[:<:]]Lon'
```

For example:

```
select * from articles where lower(title) like '[[:<:]]lon'
```

[MySQL Regexp Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

*Note: You should take @gbn's advice concerning performance issues.*

Comment: Oh, interesting. According to RegexBuddy, MySQL doesn't support word boundaries - good to hear it does. I'll notify RegexBuddy's developer right away so he can fix this.

Comment: @Tim I did not know it does either :). Just checked the manual looking for a possible answer to this question, found it, tried it, it works.

Comment: your a freaking legend.... i fumbled last night for hours using mysql regexp.... does exactly what it says on the tin with very nice results

Comment: @PhilPoore: do some comparisons with my LIKE. You'll have the same performance (or slightly worse) with regex.

Comment: technically ur no legend, i pretty sure u gotta be dead to be a legend... i just really apreaciate the advise/help.... i did read the mysql manual and tried to find as much as i could about regexp but really who can say they fully understand regexp (e.g ^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$) and esp the mysql version.... scale seams to be fine... im using it on 200000 records on 4 fields each row, and it returns within 200ms.... it'll do for me if it gets worse ill crunch the data in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with LIKE

```
WHERE MyCol LIKE 'Lon%' OR MyCol  LIKE '% Lon%'
```

However, this won't scale well because of the leading wildcard. Regex has the same problem.

You need to use [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) with stems (currently only MyISAM for 5.5) for anything scalable.

Comment: if i can i'd rather not use this as you say it wont scale well, the table is already 200,000 rows...

Comment: @PhilPoore: As I said, you need to use full text search. As the other answer says, REGEX won't scale either.